# For a 3x3 only symmetric and positive definite linear system, is Cholesky still faster than Householder?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, solver, symmetric

I am trying to solve a linear system `Ax=b` where `A` is `3x3` symmetric positive definite.

Though it is low in scale, I will have to repeat it for different `A`s millions of times. So efficiency is still important.

There are many solvers for linear systems (C++, via Eigen). 
I personally prefer: `HouseholderQr().solve()`, and `llt().solve()`, `ldlt().solve()`.

I know that when `n` is very large, solvers based on Cholesky decomposition are faster than that of Householder's. But for my case when `n` is only 3, how can I compare their relative efficiency? Is there any formula for the exact `float operation` analysis?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Cholesky will still be faster. It will be about n^3/3 flops. The only reason to use QR would be if your matrix was very ill-conditioned.

If you need to solve these systems a million times and efficiency is important, I'd recommend calling LAPACK directly. You want the `DPOSV` function.

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node26.html#1272

http://www.netlib.org/clapack/what/double/dposv.c

Comment: LAPACK is really slow for small matrices, moreover if its only 3x3 then everything should be unrolled in Eigen I would hope

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that LAPACK is really slow for small matrices. I'd be interested in seeing a benchmark between it and Eigen. Vendors also implement their own versions of LAPACK functions like DPOSV.  It would be interesting to test the INTEL MKL version of LAPACK.